# Why is Eloquent is dumping an array on save()?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
    // Look for exact matches
    foreach (Game::where("console_id", $id)->get() as $game) {
        $search = Info::where("game_title", $game->name)->first();
        if ($search) {
            $game->info_id = $search->id;
            $game->save();
            continue;
     }
```

When I run the following code, Laravel simply dumps `$game` on `$game->save()`. I've also tried `Game::find($game->id)->update(["info_id",$search->id])` and it's behaving the same way. It does actually save before it dumps but it stops execution immediately after.

Unless I'm going crazy, this isn't the expected behavior. I've searched up and down and haven't found anyone else with this issue.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are there any dumps inside model event hooks? Anything set to execute on save?

Comment: ah, yes! That's exactly what it was. For whatever reason, I had a dd in my toSearchableArray() function. Thank you!